# MongoDB stuck on clientcursormon (waiting for connections on port 27017)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, localhost

After simply installing MongoDB and creating \data\db within the MongoDB folder, I proceeded to run mongod.exe --dbpath C:\MongoDB\data\db. It runs a bunch of initandlisten code and then when it waits for connections on port 27017 it hangs and writes out mem  res:47 virt:171 mapped:80 connections:0. I am very new to Mongo and haven't found a definitive answer on why this is hanging and how to fix it.

Comment: That's not hanging, that's what the mongod process writes out to console (or your log) when it's done booting. What were you expecting?

Comment: Thanks @JohnPetrone I see now that the first cmd prompt has established a persistent connection and now I have opened another prompt to run the actual shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run the mongod.exe process as a service under Windows (to avoid it taking up a command prompt) you should following these directions for MongoDB 2.6.0 (2.6.0 has a bug with the normal approach to configuring MongoDB as a service).

> There is a known issue for MongoDB 2.6.0, SERVER-13515, which prevents
>   the use of the instructions in this section. For MongoDB 2.6.0, use
>   Manually Create a Windows Service for MongoDB to create a Windows
>   Service for MongoDB instead.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#manually-create-windows-service

For MongoDB versions 2.6.1 and later follow the normal directions:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

[Mongo waiting on 27017 even after reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403638/mongo-waiting-on-27017-even-after-reinstall/29431043#29431043)

The waiting for connections message in the console output indicates that the mongod.exe process is running successfully.

After you [install MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/?_ga=1.82566930.525730850.1428016333), you need to connect to MongoDB through mongo.exe shell using another command prompt.

As soon as you are done with that, the waiting message in first console would change to connection accepted.