# Mongo waiting on 27017 even after reinstall

Tags: mongodb, windows-8

I have uninstalled and reinstalled mongo (3.0.1), being sure i accepted the network access on windows 8, and yet i still have the same issue of "waiting on 27017".

The commands i sent are the following:

```
PS C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin> .\mongod.exe --dbpath  C:\mongodb\data
2015-04-01T21:33:46.787-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=C:\mongodb\data\journal
2015-04-01T21:33:46.790-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-04-01T21:33:46.972-0400 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2015-04-01T21:33:46.973-0400 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2015-04-01T21:33:47.134-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7436 port=27017 dbpath=C:\mongodb\data 64
-bit host=CookieMunster
2015-04-01T21:33:47.135-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2015-04-01T21:33:47.135-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.1
2015-04-01T21:33:47.136-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 534b5a3f9d10f00cd27737fbcd951032248b5952
2015-04-01T21:33:47.137-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1j-fips 15 Oct 2014
2015-04-01T21:33:47.137-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, buil
d=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-04-01T21:33:47.139-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2015-04-01T21:33:47.141-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "C:\mongodb\data" } }
2015-04-01T21:33:47.148-0400 I INDEX    [initandlisten] allocating new ns file C:\mongodb\data\local.ns, filling with ze
roes...
2015-04-01T21:33:47.587-0400 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile C:\mongodb\data\local.0, filling with ze
roes...
2015-04-01T21:33:47.589-0400 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] creating directory C:\mongodb\data\_tmp
2015-04-01T21:33:47.721-0400 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile C:\mongodb\data\local.0, size: 64MB,  t
ook 0.007 secs
2015-04-01T21:33:47.747-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

This is pending and will continue to do see endlessly.

Hitting my head against a wall and any help is wonderful.

Thanks

Comment: Waiting on 27017 or 28017 ? Please check you question once.

Comment: @dev thanks, corrected. all are 27017.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> The waiting for connections message in the console output indicates that the mongod.exe process is running successfully.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/?_ga=1.82566930.525730850.1428016333

Next you need to connect to MongoDB through mongo.exe shell using another command promt.

As soon as you are done with that, the waiting message in first console would change to connection accepted.

Comment: will try and happily accept when it works! thank you and sorry for such a noobie question.

Comment: @Waqas, How long it  takes to connect with MongoDB ? It's been 10mins and cmd prompt still says "connecting to mongodb://{ip}:27017

Answer (score 17):

For Mac users, if you have same issue then go open a new terminal window apart from the one already open and waiting for connection, go to `/usr/local/bin` and type `./mongo`

Answer (score 2):

Later, to stop MongoDB, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal where the `mongod` instance is running.

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly mentioned in above message that mongoDB is starting.

```
 2015-04-01T21:33:47.134-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7436 port=27017 dbpath=C:\mongodb\data 64
    -bit host=CookieMunster
```

If you want to connect to the mongoDB shell, open a new cmd window and write command:

```
mongo.exe
```

Comment: if it were clear to me i wouldnt be asking! thanks for the input though.

Comment: I did the same but is says "connecting to mongodb://{ip}:27017". 10mins now.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem.

In my case when I ran MongoDb on docker with the following command and expected entering mongo shell to do some query but I got meesage 'waiting for connections on port 27017' and couldn't do anything.

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 --name mongo-container mongo
```

It seems that I was supposed to launch MongoDb on the background with -d option first and then use docker exec to enter the shell

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 --name mongo-container mongo -d
docker exec -it mongo-container mongo admin
```

Answer (score 1):

If You are windows go to your root folder C:\Program Files\mongodb\Server\4.0\bin...open cmd as a Administration open cmd then type mongo start your mongodb server.

Answer (score 1):

1. open the **control panel** search for **MongoDB** file
2. Right click on it and select **repair** option
3. and click **ok** for all the options that show

Answer (score 0):

You Keep your first screen(which you are facing issue) open as it is.
Now open one more screen and go inside **mongodb** folder.
now execute `./bin/mongod.` and you can its **connected** as below .

```
2016-11-04T13:44:02.414+0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-11-04T13:50:26.990+0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51541 #1 (1 connection now open)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your mondodb local server is running. You need to install tool like robo 3T and connect to localhost://27017 to connect to local mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

After 6.0 version of Mongodb, the mongo.exe file is missing from bin folder thats why you are getting error "mongo.exe file is not recognised........."
For open the mongo shell in your cmd you have to download Mongosh file from [https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell] and unzip the file and put the mongosh file in your bin folder(at bin location 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin')  and then after restart your cmd and type '**mongosh**' after running this cmd your mongo shell will be start.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ke5g.png

if it's work then go and explore your mongodb shell.