# mongodb waiting for connections

Tags: mongodb

I downloaded mongodb 4.4, created a `data/db` folder inside my `C:` drive, then I run mongod from the bin folder, and open another cmd, navigate to the bin folder, and enter the command `mongo`. The usual stuff.

Problem is, even after doing that, I have the `"msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}` message being displayed in the mongod prompt.

I've gone through various other possible duplicates like
[Mongo waiting on 27017 even after reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403638/mongo-waiting-on-27017-even-after-reinstall)
but all of them had the same issue of not actually have started another prompt and running the `mongo` command. I seem to have done that and still don't get a connection, what am I doing wrong?

I'll attach the entire prompt message just in case;

for the prompt with `mongod`:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:39.394+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:39.401+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:39.402+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:39.404+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1912,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"DESKTOP-T5551NK"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:39.404+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:39.406+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.1","gitVersion":"ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:39.407+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 18362)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:39.410+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:39.413+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"C:/data/db/","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:39.414+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=3580M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:39.465+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1601021979:464882][1912:140716129672784], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 5 through 6"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:39.687+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1601021979:686885][1912:140716129672784], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 6 through 6"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:39.934+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1601021979:933879][1912:140716129672784], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Main recovery loop: starting at 5/5248 to 6/256"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:40.247+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1601021980:246880][1912:140716129672784], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 5 through 6"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:40.420+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1601021980:419880][1912:140716129672784], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 6 through 6"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:40.587+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1601021980:586885][1912:140716129672784], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:40.587+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1601021980:586885][1912:140716129672784], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:40.611+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":1197}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:40.611+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:40.621+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:40.625+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:40.626+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22140,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:40.636+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:41.231+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"C:/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:41.237+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-25T13:49:41.237+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

for the prompt with `mongo`

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("37c03a8f-8741-4880-9a80-32bf36700e45") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.1
---
The server generated these startup warnings when booting:
        2020-09-25T13:10:27.011+05:30: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
---
---
        Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
        metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

        The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
        and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
        improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

        To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
        To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()
---
>
```

Comment: You have started the `mongod` (the MongoDB Server). Then started the `mongo` shell. Now, you can enter some commands in the shell. See [Working with mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/mongo/index.html#working-with-the-mongo-shell).

Comment: "Waiting for connections" just means, that the database server is up and running, and that a client can now connect on the given port. This is not an error, that is the success message.

Comment: I'm not sure either of you got my question. I'll try to make it clearer.
@prasad_ Yes, I could do that but I expect the mongodb server to acknowledge the connection, to show that it got a connection request and accepted it, ie do what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: And @mtj That is correct, it isn't an error message. However, that's not my question. The question is about why the server doesn't acknowledge the connection request. ".. that a client can now connect to the port" -> That's the problem, I'm unable to.

Comment: I would think this is expected behaviour, the mongod output is just telling you: "I'm ready to accept connections". If you need to be able to tell who is connecting to your mongodb, you can probably increase the verbosity of the output or use netstat to see who is connecting on port 27017. I administer a mongodb cluster that handles ~50 writes per sec and I would not want each connection to the database written in the log file.

Comment: @hjaltist That makes sense but is still weird in that I've rarely seen anyone toggle the verbosity but they always seem to get the confirmatory message `connection accepted from xyz #1 (1 connection now open)` by default, out of the box. Secondly, I'm not sure where and how to toggle the verbosity.

Comment: @Ayush You can set the verbosity level in the configuration file. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-systemLog.verbosity
Have you tried connecting to the instance from another IP address (I'm guessing you run mongod and mongo on the same machine). Just wondering if doesn't register a connection from localhost.

Comment: @hjaltist Tried updating the verbosity to 5 for all possible things that take a verbosity. Unfortunately that doesn't help, still get the same output. And yes, I'm running both of them on the same machine. Everyone I've seen hasn't had to toggle with the verbosities. They'd run it straight out of installation on the same machine and it displays the Connection Accepted message, which is strange because I'm not really doing anything differently so it's a little mysterious why it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to be confused here. Once database is up you can just open a new cmd keeping previous session open and start mongo shell.

No need to download additional software mongoDBcompass.

Comment: Well like I explained in the question, and in the comments above, I expect the mongodb server to acknowledge the connection, to show that it got a connection request and accepted it, ie do what it's supposed to be doing.